# Instantiate multiple view controllers from a single table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am designing an app where I have a table view and I want each row to point to a different view controller and then be able to go back to the table view. I know I have to use a navigation controller to do this but how do I make each row go to a seperate view controller?

For example if I have a table view of shapes and colors and I pick the row colors, I want to load a different view controller to work with colors but maintain the hierarchy.

Please excuse my language usage, I am just starting out with Objective - C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple if condition in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     ViewController1 *obj1 = [[ViewController1 alloc]init];
     ViewController1 *obj2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
     if(indexPath.row == 0)
     {
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj1 animated:YES];
     } else {

         [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj2 animated:YES];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should go to table view delegate and check which row was selected using – `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Based on the row selected, determine which view controller you want to go to. Make an instance of that view controller and push it to navigation controller.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: newViewController animated:YES];
```